# Problems with refreshing page and event handling ($emit and $on)

Tags: vue.js

I'm using an EventBus in my code so I can manage how my navbar changes depending on the user that has logged in, if he's admin the navbar will have more functions.

The fact is that when I log in, the login component emits something with an $emit, this event is recieved by another component, which is the navbar.

That works fine, if he's logged in and he's an admin, he'll have more things to interact with in the navbar, but ***when I refresh the page is like the events desappear*** and the navbar works like there's no one even logged in.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

### Login.vue

I call these methods when an user logs in and is also an admin.

```
emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')
    },
adminMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('isadmin', 'isadmin')
    }
```

### Navbar.vue

The navbar option 'Users'

```
<li v-if="auth=='loggedin' && admin=='isadmin'" class="nav-item">
                    <router-link class="nav-link" to="/users">Users</router-link>
</li>
```

### This is the method login() that emits the event

```
login () {
      axios.post('signin', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }).then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data.token)
        const token = localStorage.usertoken
        const decoded = jwtDecode(token)
        this.admin = decoded.sub.isAdmin
        console.log('¿Es admin? ' + this.admin)
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
        //alert('Logueado correctamente')
        this.emitMethod()
        if (this.admin === true) {
          this.adminMethod()
        }
        router.push({ name: 'Profile' })
        
      }).catch(err => {
        this.password = ''
        alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')
        console.log(err)
      })
    },
    emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')
    },
    adminMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('isadmin', 'isadmin')
    }
  }
```

### And this the script section of the component Navbar.vue

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      auth: '',
      user: '',
      admin: '',
      users: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    logout () {
      localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('logged-in', status => {
      this.auth = status
    })
    EventBus.$on('isadmin', status => {
      this.admin = status
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh the page, all components will be reset and will start from the initial state again. You need to either detect that the user is logged-in in Login.vue initialization and emit the event OR pass some prop to the Navbar component that would inform is the user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link or some code so I can see how to do it correctly?

Comment: You need to have a way to detect if the user is already logged when you load the page, then run the `EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')` command to make the Navbar.vue aware. There are multiple ways to do it, if you can provide more snippets of your code I can give you some suggestions.

Comment: I have edited the post with more code, I don't really know how to detect if the user is already logged when I refresh the page

Comment: @CharlyRos In my answer I have mentioned that you must check if user logged in. But someone downgraded nevertheless my answer is correct. Anyway if you using PHP you can pass session variable to Vue.js if user logged in. For example : `$login = codeToGetUserFromSession;` Then pass `$login` to Vue as variable and check it everywhere you need. If you provide more code from backend or if you use framework tell the name I will try to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you logged in and redirected to home admin page. In your code you write the function that only fire event in **Login.vue** guess on click login button. But after login process and redirecting to admin homepage when you refresh the page there is no $emit event (`EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')`) in current page. And that is why your Navbar can not get if somebody is logged in or not.

You must check if user logged in every time when you refresh page and **$emit logged-in** event after this check. Then your program will work as you want